# Typings install won't install existing definitions

Tags: typescript-typings

I have migrated from tsd to typings.  And am in the process of converting my gulpfile.js to gulpfile.ts.  Hence I would like to use type definitions for such things as 'gulp-rename', 'gulp-uglify' etc.

In the case of 'gulp-uglify'  it appears that the type definition exists:

> https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/gulp-uglify/gulp-uglify.d.ts

And if I run the command **typings search gulp-uglify** I get the following response:

```js
NAME        SOURCE HOMEPAGE                                  DESCRIPTION VERSIONS UPDATED
gulp-uglify dt     https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify             1        2016-03-16T15:55:26.000Z
```

My question is how do I install this type definition?  I have tried variations of the following:

```js
typings install gulp-uglify --save
typings install gh~gulp-uglify --save
typings install dt~gulp-uglify --save
typings install github~gulp-uglify --save
```

No luck.  Getting variations of '**Unable to find "gulp-uglify" ("npm") in the registry**'
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what version of typings do you use?

Comment: @AlekseyL. am running the latest version of typings:  1.3.1

Comment: @AlekseyL. well, it turns out, when I checked the version of typings from the command line (typings -v) it showed 0.8.1, whereas in package.json it showed 1.3.1.  I did a 'npm install typings -g' from the command line which updated typings globally to 1.3.1.  NOW IT WORKS!  Thx for the hint

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
typings install dt~gulp-uglify --global --save
```

Though you might want to use "--save-dev" for "gulp-uglify"

Make sure you use latest version of typings (currenctly that would be 1.3.1)

Comment: Bummer, tried it but got:  typings ERR! message Unable to find "dt~gulp-uglify" ("npm") in the registry.

Comment: please add a note  to your answer that you should use the latest version of typings 1.3.1 or above, and I will mark yours as the answer. once i upgraded with 'npm install typings -g' your answer worked